# FOSUserBundle login check exception "Array to string conversion"

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed FOSUserBundle and followed the example in this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html and each time I try to login symfony shows me this exception:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

So this is my class `User` that extneds from `BaseUser`:

```
namespace OCUserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser ;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OCUserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


}
```

`securit.yml`:

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     /platform
            anonymous:    true
```

and this is my `routing.yml`:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

and this is the table in my database:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TUA.png)

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Does your OCUserBundle override FOSUserBundle ?

namespace UserBundle;

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class OCUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

It also may need that you configure fos_user options in config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: OCUserBundle\Entity\User
```

(And when in doubt, always clear the cache).

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the constructor in your user class:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
```

and maybe in your config:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: OCUserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: Nope, the constructor exist and the configuration is correct but still no results

Comment: affound the solution this problem in vertion to symfony

Comment: can you explain the problem?

Comment: the default present betwin the version in symfony3 and symfony 2.so after changed the version to 2.8 th'is problem  result